# pandas.errors.EmptyDataError, but the file is not empty

Tags: python, pandas, error-handling

I have written the following code (shortened) to retrieve data from netCDF files, and save them as a time series in a temp file in each loop for each i,j cell:

```
for i in range(0,400):
    for j in range(0,120):
       with open('file_temp.tmp', 'w') as out_temp:
           out_temp.write('header1'+'\t'+'header2'+'\n')
           for yr in range(1990,2011):
               (get data from netCDF)
               out_temp.write(str(val1)+'\t'+str(val2)+'\n')
       df=pd.read_csv('file_temp.tmp', delimiter='\t')
```

But in the very last line of reading the file by Pandas, I get this error:

```
 line 1605, in __init__
self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 565, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

I would appreciate your help

Comment: Is there a reason for the three for loops? NetCDF files can be easily read in one chunk as far as I know.

Comment: Yes you are right, but I am not only retrieving data from netCDFs, but doing some spatial and temporal investigation on them to produce some correlation maps. So I need to use loops to be able to process the data of each cell

Comment: Isn't that the purpose of pandas? Being able to process the data of all cells without any for loops? Except if you alter the data in cells that are coming "next" in the iteration, there is no need for loops at all. And even then there are some nice methods like `cumsum` etc. that allow to avoid explicit loops.

Comment: Dear @Scotty1- thanks for your suggestions, but my case now is not this right now. I found the loops a better solution for this specific case. 
I have a problem with Pandas itself! in which I come up with this strange error that no solution in the stackoverflow worked out for me. I would appreciate your suggestions for this specific problem, if you would have any. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, back to topic. Could you please post a fully working code sample? Especially when the data is open access, having something to execute in the console is always nice.

Comment: Unfortunately my data are not publicly available and I am not allowed to share them elsewhere. But you may find the complete code using the link below:

https://www.4shared.com/file/RMK0wqAFda/correl_map_1990-2010.html

Thanks

Comment: You do not have to share all of the data. Just a tiny excerpt, possibly filled with dummy values, will help. The same is true for the code: Just post a minimum working example. No one has the time/capability to check a complete code without even having the data.

Comment: I found another solution that works much more practically. I did put as an answer to my question. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

To whom this problem might be a concern, I found a kind of solution, which might seem a bit naive, but works and can be considered as a shortcut at least in urgent cases:

I split my script into two scripts, one for extracting the data and writing them in the form of time series into csv files, and another script to read those csv files and further process them. Something like:

First script:

```
for i in range(0,400):
    for j in range(0,120):
       with open('file_temp.tmp', 'w') as out_temp:
       out_temp.write('header1'+'\t'+'header2'+'\n')
           for yr in range(1990,2011):
               (get data from netCDF)
               out_temp.write(str(val1)+\
               '\t'+str(val2)+'\n')
```

Second script:

```
df=pd.read_csv('file_temp.tmp', delimiter='\t')
(do further analysis)
```

If you are using Unix or Linux, a bash script can run both of the scripts together (successive) and you don't have to run one after the other